# Excel replace column name with cell value in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to replace a columnname with a cell value in a formula:

[image]

Seems like a simple problem, but I can't find the right way to dynamically (based on another cell value) create the column name for the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("table[@"&E1&"]")
```